# Is it possible to switch variants in the value of a mutable reference to an enum?

Tags: enums, rust

Is it possible to switch variants in the value of a mutable reference (`&mut E<T>`) without additional constraints on `T`, and without resorting to unsafe code?

That is, given an enum:

```
enum E<T> {
    VariantA(T),
    VariantB(T)
}
```

What is the correct way of writing this:

```
let x: E<???> = E::VariantA(??);
change_to_variant_b(&mut x);
assert_eq!(x, E::VariantB(??));
```

Comment: Looks like something that would be addressed by the closed [`replace_with` RFC (#1736)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1736).

Comment: As an alternative, would changing it to a `struct` with a `T` and a plain `enum` work in your case?

Comment: @ChrisEmerson It very much would. I just thought that there must be a way for variants to assume the contents of their siblings since it intuitively doesn't run counter to Rusts ownership model.

Comment: I'm unsure whether this is close enough to the original problem to warrant an answer, but if you are willing to have a variant that does not contain a `T`, and to tolerate an "impossible" path though the code, I've written a safe, stable, version of `change_to_variant_b` [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f731602e09c7f8be91fd4a21d8c0e7ca) which uses `std::mem::replace`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am going to go on a limb here and say **No**.

---

It is possible with just a minor change to the signature though:

```
fn change_to_variant_b<T>(e: E<T>) -> E<T> {
    match e {
        E::VariantA(t) => E::VariantB(t),
        E::VariantB(t) => E::VariantB(t),
    }
}
```

---

It is possible using `unsafe`:

```
fn change_to_variant_b<T>(e: &mut E<T>) {
    use std::ptr;

    unsafe {
        match ptr::read(e as *const _) {
            E::VariantA(t) => ptr::write(e as *mut _, E::VariantB(t)),
            E::VariantB(t) => ptr::write(e as *mut _, E::VariantB(t)),
        }
    }
}
```

---

It is possible with additional bounds (`Default`, or `Clone`):

```
fn change_to_variant_b<T: Default>(e: &mut E<T>) {
    match std::mem::replace(e, E::VariantA(T::default())) {
        E::VariantA(t) => e = E::VariantB(t),
        E::VariantB(t) => e = E::VariantB(t),
    }
}
```

Comment: Props for the clear answer and for listing alternatives in detail. I need `&mut E<T>` because I'm mutably iterating over a slice, so I can't(?) move elements out of it temporarily for the first solution to work.

Comment: Also, as a paragmatic solution, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431973/how-to-change-variants-of-mutable-reference#comment72014156_42431973

Comment: @Doe: Oh, if Chris solution works for you then definitely roll with it. It's always a bit difficult to come up with alternatives working on reduced examples since it's unclear what the boundaries of what can and cannot be changed are.

Comment: @perhaps "solution" wasn't the best word to describe Chris's comment (as it side-steps the issue entirely). However, for most visitors who are looking for a solution, Chris's comment will likely suffice. **No** is probably the only answer that meets the criteria in the OP.

Comment: @Doe: Yes, Chris, like mine, are more work-arounds. If you are (1) stuck with the `enum` and (2) stuck with the signature of the function and (3) stuck with no unsafe/no bounds... then you cannot.

Comment: I'm coming to this question from Google, how come nobody suggested `std::mem::replace` on `self`?

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative for this particular case, you could consider changing to a struct with a `T` and a plain enum:

```
struct Outer<T> {
    val: T,
    kind: Inner,
}

impl<T> Outer<T> {
    fn promote_to_b(&mut self) {
        self.kind.promote_to_b()
    }
}

enum Inner {
    VariantA,
    VariantB,
}

impl Inner {
    fn promote_to_b(&mut self) {
        if let Inner::VariantA = *self {
            *self = Inner::VariantB;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to switch variants in the value of a mutable reference

As [Matthieu M. said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42436853/155423), the general answer is "no". The reason is that doing so would leave the enum in an indeterminate state, which would allow accessing undefined memory, which would allow breaking Rust's safety guarantees. As an example, let's pretend that this code compiled without error:

```
impl<T> E<T> {
    fn promote_to_b(&mut self)  {
        if let E::VariantA(val) = *self {
            // Things happen
            *self = E::VariantB(val);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is once you've moved the value from `self` into `val`, what should happen to the memory representing `T` inside `self`?

If we copied the bits and then a panic occurred in "Things happen", the destructor for both `val` and the `T` inside `self` would run, but since these point at the same data, this would lead to a double free.

If we didn't copy the bits, then you couldn't safely access the `val` inside "Things happen", which would be of marginal usefulness.

---

The by-value solution works because the compiler can track who is supposed to call the destructor: the function itself. Once you are inside the function, the compiler knows which specific lines might need to free the value and properly calls them in case of panic.

The `Clone` or `Default` solution works because you never move the value out of the original enum. Instead, you can replace the original enum with a dummy value and take ownership of the original (using `Default`) or duplicate the entire original value (using `Clone`).

---

The [`replace_with` RFC (#1736)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1736) proposed to add a method that would allow this to work while ensuring that proper memory semantics were upheld, but that RFC was not accepted.